# Linking errors when adding AdMob to IOS cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: objective-c, admob, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i trying to add AdMob to cocos2d-x 3.2 simple game
using Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.1
i following the tutorials in 
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios
and 
http://plaincode.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/example-of-admob-integration-in-cocos2d.html

and after adding the -ObjC flag in the "Other Linker Flags"

I'm getting linking errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_GCControllerDidDisconnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[GCControllerConnectionEventHandler observerConnection:disconnection:] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCController-iOS.o)
  "_GCControllerDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[GCControllerConnectionEventHandler observerConnection:disconnection:] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCController-iOS.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2dx iOS.a(UIVideoPlayerIOS.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCController-iOS.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GCControllerConnectionEventHandler)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      -[UIVideoViewWrapperIos dealloc] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(UIVideoPlayerIOS.o)
      -[UIVideoViewWrapperIos setURL::] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(UIVideoPlayerIOS.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[UIVideoViewWrapperIos dealloc] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(UIVideoPlayerIOS.o)
      -[UIVideoViewWrapperIos setURL::] in libcocos2dx iOS.a(UIVideoPlayerIOS.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when i removing the -ObjC flag 
then I'm getting :

```
<Google> Category methods are not loaded. Make sure you link the Google Mobile Ads library using one of the -ObjC, -force_load, or -all_load linker flags. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios for more information.
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: I would suggest using plugin-x

Comment: what do you mean , is there any ready made plugin for admob iOS?

Comment: yes, it's called plugin-x, it comes with cocos2d-x, google it.

Comment: plugin-x from what i know its just the definition to make plugins 
but i didn't found any implementation for adMob for iOS

Comment: https://github.com/cocos2d-x/plugin-x
you dont need to install it manually, it's already inside cocos2d/plugin inside your game's project directory.

Comment: there's a sample for AdMob and Flurry there

Comment: Thanks i see something ...
_admob = dynamic_cast<ProtocolAds*>(PluginManager::getInstance()->loadPlugin("AdsAdmob"));

Comment: does any one know why this problem arises once you add AdMob if it is being referenced to from cocos library ?

Answer (score 31):

> **-ObjC** Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an Objective-C class or category.(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html)

In cocos2d-x 3.2[image]

CCController-iOS.mm -> `#import <GameController/GameController.h>`

UIVideoPlayerIOS.mm ->`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

so you got those errors.

**Solution:** 
Just add following frameworks BuildSettings -> Build Phase -> Link Binary with libraries

```
MediaPlayer.framework
GameController.framework
```

Comment: Thanks Jasio. Just to make it clear, the frameworks should be added in your project, not in cocos

Comment: Just as a note for those integrating the soomla cocos2dx store framework.  This might help too.

Comment: can anyone help me ? i got only 3 of those messages that @user63898 got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734127/what-is-other-linker-flags-in-xcode-build-settings

Answer (score 1):

Yes the reason was -ObjC flag added for AdMob support. I have add MediaPlayer.framework to my project and it solved problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the path to `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` in `Other Linker Flags` worked for me. Note I'm using Mopub with Cocos2d-x 3.0.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/linking-errors-when-adding-admob-to-ios-cocos2d-x-3-2/15672

Answer (score 0):

AdMob iOS SDK version 7.0 is released as a framework. You don't need to add -ObjC linker option and extra dependencies if you use it. Also it is optimised for iOS 8.0. If you switch to 7.0 all your linking errors will disappear.