# What is "Other Linker Flags" issue in Xcode build settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a cocos2d-x project that I'm working on, I added cocoapods to it and originally all that was in "Other linker flags" was $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_BEGIN) AND $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_END) everything works fine but then I added google-mobile-ads and amazon ads to my pod file and ran pod install and it said to add $(inherited) to my other linker flags target and I did but then I get this error, If I remove ($inherited) everything builds fine, if I keep ($inherited) and remove $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_BEGIN) AND $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_END) everything builds fine, but when I have all 3, I get the error ? [image]

Comment: Just check once in your Framework Search Paths, Sometimes multiple path attached here. Just remove duplicates - Project -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths - Double click and check there.

Comment: i followed this and just added the gamecontroller framework but how come it build fine before without gamecontroller when I just have $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_BEGIN) & (_COCOS_LIB_IOS_END) without adding the '$(inherited)' flag ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844766/linking-errors-when-adding-admob-to-ios-cocos2d-x-3-2

Answer (score 0):

```
Add config in pod file.

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['pod name', 'pod name',].include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: i followed this and just added the gamecontroller framework but how come it built fine before without gamecontroller when I just have $(_COCOS_LIB_IOS_BEGIN) & (_COCOS_LIB_IOS_END) without adding the '$(inherited)' flag ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844766/linking-errors-when-adding-admob-to-ios-cocos2d-x-3-2